# How to apply upvote functionality with corresponding Model in Template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-orm

I am developing a `quora` like app in Django but facing two problem. I want, in Question DetailView if user have not upvoted the answer then it will show the option of upvote and the total vote.

Here is my html template.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} {{ question.title }} {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h3><i>{{ question.title }}</i></h3>
    {{ question.description }}
    {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
        <br>
        <div>
        <p>{{ answer.answer_text }} <span style="font-size: 15px">by [{{ answer.user }}]</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'answer:detail' question.id %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="vote">
            <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="{{ answer.id }}">
            {% for upvote in answer.upvote_set.all %}
                {% if upvote.user == request.user %}

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"
                           value="Downvote|{{ answer.upvote_set.all.count }}">
                {% else %}
                    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upvote|{{ answer.upvote_set.all.count }}">
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% empty %}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Upvote|{{ 0 }}">

            {% endfor %}
        </form>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse


# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_text = models.TextField()
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # upvote = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('answer:answer_by_me', kwargs={'pk': self.user.id})


class Upvote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answers = models.ForeignKey(Answer)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

It's showing both upvote and downvote button if user and any other user voted already.
I can't use break keyword if user's vote found in the `answer.upvote_set.all` even I can't use membership operator like        `if request.user in answer.upvote_set.all` because it returns upvote object queryset. How should i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a [**`custom tag`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) for that.

Create a file in `templatetags` folder of your app named `upvote_tags.py`.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def has_upvoted(user, answer):
    return user.id in list(answer.upvote_set.all().values_list("user", flat=True))
```

Now in your template you can use it like.

```
# load tag at top of your html.
{% load upvote_tags %}

...
# remove your loop and use condition as below 
{% if has_upvoted request.user answer %}
   # show downvote button for this answer
{% else %}
   # show upvote button for this answer
{% endif %}
```

You also have to make entry of your tag file in TEMPLATE list under libraries keyword in your settings.py.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'libraries':{
               # make your file entry here.
               'upvote_tags': 'app_name.templatetags.upvote_tags',
            }
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really helpful and well explained answer.

Comment: @satendra - nice answer, but could you clarify which loop you are referring to in the template? I presume it comes after `{% for upvote in answer.upvote_set.all %}`. Could you maybe add the next outer loop to the answer so that its clear where it sits?

Comment: Hey, @AndyClifton there is no need to add a loop in the template. `has_upvoted` tag is already doing this.

Comment: @satendra - so, explicitly, are you saying "replace `{% for upvote in answer.upvote_set.all %}...{% endfor %}` in the original question with `{% if has_upvoted request.user answer %} ... {% endif %}` in your answer? (I count at least two for loops and so its not clear to me which loops you are referring to. Thanks!)

Comment: @AndyClifton I am referring to the inner loop `{% for upvote in answer.upvote_set.all %}` above loop is fine